# usarsim_inf not working with teleop_twist_keyboard

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I am trying to **navigate a robot(P3AT) spawned in usarsim environment using keyboard** from another computer where ros is installed, but its not working, please help me out, i tried a lot but can't figure out the mistake.

**I am following these steps given below:-**

1. In one terminal Run **$roscore**
2. Spawn a Robot in usarsim, for this i am following these steps:-

**A.** Start usarsim, which is in another windows machine.

**B.** In another ros terminal Run the the following command:

```
    $roslaunch usarsim_inf usarsim.launch
```

This spawns a P3AT robot in usarsim environment. and following output appears:-

```
    ... logging to /home/cr-lab-tu/.ros/log/e3f28b38-4729-11e4-959a-2c27d7efa01b/roslaunch-crlabtu-HP-Z800-Workstation-3277.log
    Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
    Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
    Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

    started roslaunch server http://crlabtu-HP-Z800-Workstation:39055/

    SUMMARY
    ========

    PARAMETERS
       * /rosdistro
       * /rosversion
       * /usarsim/hostname
       * /usarsim/odomSensor
       * /usarsim/port
       * /usarsim/robotType
       * /usarsim/startPosition

    NODES
      /
        RosSim (usarsim_inf/usarsim_node)

    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

    core service [/rosout] found
    process[RosSim-1]: started with pid [3297]
    [ERROR] [1411920693.631497443]: Unknown conf type Camera
```

3. Then i run teleop_twist_keyboard using the following command:-

   ```
    $ rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
   ```
4. Run the slam_gmapping node, using the following command:-

   ```
    $ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=lms200 _odom_frame:=odom
   ```
5. Now i can press the keyboard keys to navigate the Robot in usarsim environment, but when i do it nothing happens and **following error gets added each time when i press the keyboard keys** to navigate the robot, on the terminal where i launch the usarsim.launch file. **errors are given below:-**

   ```
    [ERROR] [1411920792.568087748]: usarsimInf::peerMsg: not handling type SW_SEN_ENCODER
   ```
6. I have run **$rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph** and i found the [following rqt_graph-click to view](https://tucrlab.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/screenshot-from-2014-09-27-16_50_02.png)
7. Then i've run the follownig command:

   ```
    $ rostopic echo /cmd_vel
   ```

This generated following [graph click to view](https://tucrlab.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/screenshot-from-2014-09-27-17_18_32.png)

**Please help me to figure out the error if any or correct way to navigate through Keyboard.**

***Note: I am using ROS-Fuerte on UBUNTU 10.04 LTS***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193669/usarsim_inf-not-working-with-teleop_twist_keyboard/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-06**:
You've already asked this before. Please update your [old question](http://answers.ros.org/question/193335/teleop_twist_keyboard-not-working-with-executive_usarsim/) instead of asking a new question.

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-06**:
hello @ahendrix, in the old question i asked regarding t**eleop_twist_keyboard's issue with executive_usarsim package**,

but in this question i asked that **usarsim_inf not working with teleop_twist_keyboard**.

so **they are not the same question because they are dealing with different package**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please type following commands on the terminal window of PC2.

```
terminal-1:
    $ echo “source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash” >> ~/.bashrc
    $ . ~/.bashrc
    $ sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-rosdep ros-fuerte-brown-remotelab ros-fuerte-control ros-fuerte-common-msgs ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping ros-fuerte-hector-slam
    $ rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
    $ echo “source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash” >> ~/.bashrc
    $ mkdir ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
    $ source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
    $ rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
    $ source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
    $ roscd
    $ cd sandbox
    $ git clone git://git.assembla.com/usarsim.git
        (Under the proxy, try “git clone http://git.assembla.com/usarsim.git&#8221")
    $ rosmake usarsim_inf
    
    At this point if making usarsim_inf is successful, then use these steps,
    
    terminal-1: $ roscore
    terminal-2: $ export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`
                    $ roslaunch usarsim_inf usarsim.launch
    terminal-3: $ rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
```

now navigate using key. It works.

---

Originally posted by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) with karma: 77 on 2014-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-13**:
I think `'PWD'` should use backticks instead of single quotes.

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-14**:
Thank you sooo much @sumant it worked... :)

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-18**:
yes @gvdhoorn it is

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`
```

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2016-10-05**:
Now one year later, i on a new PC , i am facing the same problem.

```
 [ERROR] [1475649575.941420195]: Unknown conf type Camera
```

please help. The above answer do not work for me.

I would like to know the reason behind.